# Django Rest Framework URL parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Currently i have to display all customers for a specific workshop then I am using following url:
http://localhost:8000/customer-list/?workshop_id=1

and in my view I have following implementation:

```
class CustomerList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['customer_name']
    
    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        workshop_id = self.request.query_params.get('workshop_id', None)
        if workshop_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(workshop_id=workshop_id)
        return queryset
    def list(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        workshop_id = self.request.query_params.get('workshop_id', None)
        
        if not (workshop_id):
            return Response({"status": "Required field not found."},
                                        status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        return super(CustomerList, self).list(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

Url Path looks like this:

```
path('customer-list/', views.CustomerList.as_view(),name='customer_list'),
```

But I want my url should look like this:
http://localhost:8000/{workshop_id}/customer-list

How can I set my URL path:

and how can I get workshop_id in customer view to apply filters:

I have tried to change url pattern but it did not work.

Comment: `I have tried to change url pattern but it did not work.` What did you change it to that didn't work?

Comment: I have tried like this:path('workshop_id/customer-list/', views.CustomerList.as_view(),name='customer_list') where workshop_id is a dynamic id. My Question is How can i get workshop_id in views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass `workshop_id` as an URL parameter just define it in the path, for example:

```py
path('<int:workshop_id>/customer-list/', views.CustomerList.as_view(),name='customer_list')
```

And you can get the parameter from `self.kwarg`:

```py
class CustomerList(ListAPIView):
    ...
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        workshop_id = self.kwargs.get('workshop_id', None)
        ...
```